# Bukkit Minecraft setIngredient Material id colon issue

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to use a full id of a block in the getmaterial part of the code below. this does not work any way that i try.

I cannot find any documentation supporting this issue of handling an id which contains a 'colon :' .

Snip: (Example the `5758:6` below does not work and the string name neither.)

```
emerald.setIngredient('L', Material.getMaterial("5758:6"));
```

`Material.getMaterial(406) //this is expecting an integer so i cannot give it two numbers`

`Material.getMaterial(406:1) //this fails as is expecting int`

Comment: is an error thrown by any chance?

Comment: No error on that no.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `emerald` is a `ShapedRecipe` object (since you're using the `setIngredient(char, Material)` method), then you can also use the `setIngredient(char, MaterialData)` method instead.  You could construct the `MaterialData` object you want using the (deprecated...) `MaterialData(int, byte)` constructor.  Your new code would look like:

```
emerald.setIngredient('L', new MaterialData(5758, 6));
```

The colon in the "full id of a block" is just separating the "id" and "data" values.  I think this will do what you're looking for, but if not, let me know so I can clarify.

Comment: Ok sorry what would i have to do for that to work i have tried putting that into place but the MaterialData is missing.

Comment: @Derple I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "missing".  Is it simply a matter of needing the `import org.bukkit.material.MaterialData;` statement at the top, or is it missing in another sense?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're supposed to be dealing with that number colon thing.  Instead, if you want to get to, say, the `BRICK` material, use `Material.BRICK` or `Material.valueOf("BRICK")`.  If you want to find the name of a `Material m`, use `m.name()` which returns a `String`.

Comment: But that doesnt help the issue. I need to get item by an id as the string name is not working.

Comment: Why do you need to use id?  Directly using ids is deprecated.

Comment: I need to reference a block from a modpack. And i only know to use id's for that.